# Скачивание, и последующая отправка изображения Ajax

Tags: файлы, ajax, php, post, javascript

Добрый день. Такая задача. Есть php скрипт на стороне сервера, который через ajax пост запрос получает картинку из input[type=file]. Как можно, с помощью JavaScript, отправит ему картинку не через input file, а из ссылки с удаленного сервера? То есть нужно сначала скачать этот файл (картинку), потом передать через Ajax. Но как?

Comment: пипл говорит что можно отрисовать ее в canvas, но мне что-то не верится.

Comment: отрисовать можно, а вот передать нельзя :)

Comment: Через Canvas тоже нельзя, политика безопасности зарубит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только если на удаленном сервере включен [CORS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), иначе только [cURL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).